# Setting Scanner dpi with TWAINDotNet: setting dpi >1200 fails

Tags: vb.net, twain, twaindotnet

I am trying to use the TWAINDotNet API to control an Epson Scanner. I have almost everything working, but I can't set the dpi properly.

If I set the API at 300, 600 or even 1199 dpi, the scanner works as expected. Unfortunately when I try to set the dpi to 1200 or above, I get a TWAINException indicating "TwainDotNet.TwainNative.ConditionCode.CapabilitySequenceError". 
The scanner is certainly capable of 1200pi (as well as even high dpi values).

I am using TWAINDotNet from VB.Net 2010

I appreciate any comments.

Comment: What if you show the user interface of the scanner and set dpi to 1200 from there? Can you do scan successfully?

Comment: Yes If I select 1200 from the Scanner UI then it scans correctly. My problem is that I need to completely automate the process. I also tried SaraffTwain but it lists 1184 different resolutions from  1dpi to 1184dpi.

Comment: Please also try Twack and see if you can scan successfully. If the same issue happens, check the error log to get more information. http://www.twain.org/scannerdriverdevelopers/specification-and-tools.html

Comment: Rachel Installed and tried to scan with Twack. If I use the UI, it works, but if I disable the UI and try to setup the scanner, I get a TWAIN Error: Cannot Enable Source. CAP_ENABLEDSUIONLY is not supported.

Comment: Ian, according to the error message, the cause of the issue is that the TWAIN driver of your scanner doesn't support the CAP_ENABLEDSUIONLY capability.

Comment: I have dug into this some more. The Twain call to get the possible dpi resolutions returns a list 1134 long going from 50 to 1184. 1200 dpi in not on this list nor are other resolutions I know this scanner is capable of (2400, 3600, 12800 etc). Since 1200 is not is the list, the call to set the resolution fails. So why is 1200 not in the list returned by the call to get capability?

Comment: Good to know that. You may want to check with the support of Epson and see if they have a newer version of TWAIN driver which supports the CAP_ENABLEDSUIONLY capability.

Comment: Based on comments from Epson, it appears that if you don't set the area to be scanned to something less than 8.5x11, the maximum dpi is 1184. They recommended setting the area to be scanned to, for instance, 4x6. This should allow higher resolutions.  The way that TwainDotNet is  configured, it sets the area to be scanned after the attempt to set the resolution hence the inability to set the DPI to 1200. I have made the changes to TwainDotNet but won't have a chance to test until next week.

Comment: Good to know the progress you made. Looking forward to the test results!

Answer (score 1):

Working with Epson, I was able to solve the problem. On the V550 scanner, the maximum resolution is a fuction of the area to be scanned. For a full 8.5inx11in page, the maximum resolution is 1184dpi.

To set resolutions higher than 1200dpi, you need to set the area to be scanned to a smaller region.

To correct the issue, in datasource.cs, all you have to do is move the

```
if (settings.Area != null)
{
    NegotiateArea(settings);
}
```

before

```
if (settings.Resolution != null)
{
    NegotiateColour(settings);
    NegotiateResolution(settings);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Twain's "CapabilitySequenceError" means, "Capability has dependency on other capability". It will depend on your specific scanner what else you need to set before setting the dpi to 1200.

In some cases, the scanner expects caps to be set in a particular order.  Off the top of my head, perhaps you need to change the scanning speed to 'slow' (I'm just guessing).

Comment: That give me somewhere else to look. Looking at the Epson Scan Applet, it was not obvious what else would need to be set before you set 1200 dpi. Scanner speed was a good guess but doesn't seem to be a setable parameter on the scanner. IT seem to adjust the speed as needed.